# figure caption on hover center text

Tags: javascript, css

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sLdhsbou/ I would like to have the "x" that appears when hovering absolutely centered no matter what the size of the image is.

In addition why is it that there is no transition when the mouse moves outside the figure as there is when the mouse moves in?

```
<table border=1 style="width: 100%;">
    <TR><TD COLSPAN=6 STYLE="border-bottom: medium solid gray;">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    <tr>
        <td class="left" style="width: 25%; background-color: cyan;">
            <table border=2 style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: thin solid #ff9900;">
                        <div class="img-wrap">
                            <figure class="cap-bottom">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
                                <figcaption>
                                   <div class="icon icon-image"></div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan=2 style="padding-top: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">
            <center><span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">lorem ipsum</span></center>
            <br/>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, prima brute at cum, ius tota fugit error te, eum an quod invidunt. an facer fierent iudicabit vix, pri at illud diceret probatus. maiorum ponderum omittantur te per, pri alterum propriae postulant at. ut pro nostro petentium salutandi.
            <p/>est dico stet quaeque no, ei eos dolores dignissim. mei dicunt indoctum deterruisset an, recteque moderatius eu nam. per praesent efficiantur ut, ad mel assum laoreet tincidunt. ad qui agam nullam causae, ut mei minim clita, ut movet verterem democritum est.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <TR><TD COLSPAN=6 STYLE="border-top: thin solid gray;">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
</table>
```

```
figure img{display:block}

figure
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0; padding:0
}
figcaption
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255,204,51,0.75);
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease
}
figure:hover figcaption
{
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.cap-left figcaption{bottom:0;left:-100%}
.cap-left:hover figcaption{left:0}
.cap-right figcaption{bottom:0;right:-100%}
.cap-right:hover figcaption{right:0}
.cap-top figcaption{left:0;top:-100%}
.cap-top:hover figcaption{top:0}
.cap-bottom figcaption{left:0;bottom:-100%}
.cap-bottom:hover figcaption{bottom:0}

.icon { line-height: 1; }
.icon:link, .icon:visited, .icon:focus { color: #000; }
.icon-image
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 47%;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.icon-image:before{content: "x"}
```

Comment: use for center x - transform: translate - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/u5vqhhst/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.cap-bottom:hover figcaption {
  top: 0;
}

.cap-bottom figcaption {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

change your css as above :)

hope this helps you